# Reload or reinitialize angular form after posting data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have an angular form to add data in database.I am using angular-fullstack by yeoman.

Now, once data is posted, I can clear ty the form values by assigning an empty object to form scope.

However, I can not add more values without reloading the page.

Also, I have tried this:

```
 var original = $scope.permission;
                 $scope.reset(original);

$scope.reset= function(original){
  $scope.permission= angular.copy(original)
            $scope.form2.$setPristine();
            $scope.form2.$setUntouched();
}
```

But has not helped.

Note: $route.reload() is not suitable for me in this case therefore I am trying to find alternatives to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your requirements are. But as for $route.reload, I think you're injecting the module incorrectly. There are two things you need to do to get $route.reload() to work. After you've added angular-route.js as a script tag:

1) Change

```
angular.module('createProjectApp', ['$route'])
```

to

```
angular.module('createProjectApp', ['ngRoute'])
```

According to the documentation, the correct module name is ngRoute
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

2) In your controller, you need to include $route as a parameter. Then you can use $reload.route() in that particular controller like so:

```
createProjectApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $route) {
    $scope.reload = function(){
        $reload.route();
    }
}
```

Comment: ngRoute still gives the same error despite of having installed the module and having done everything as suggested. I doubt it has something to do with angular fullstack structure.

Comment: hmm.. would you like to upload your code to plunkr? Otherwise, it's difficult to see what the issue is.

Comment: Okay, I figured that $route wont help me in the case. Now I am left to figure out the way to reinitialize the form so that more data can be posted without having to reload the page every time. I am still wondering why did it not work with pristine and untouched flags?

Answer (score 0):

That error seems to be relevant. If I understand correctly you are trying to inject ngRoute module as dependency into your createProjectApp. In that case you should do something like this:

```
angular.module('createProjectApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

and make sure you have proper script tag in the header:

```
<script src="angular-route.js">
```

Hope this helps.